# Subgraph, HighlightGraph not acting as expected

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorica

I'm trying to create a simple graph from a matrix and then highlight a particular subgraph.  My code (simplified from a bigger task) is as follows.  I keep getting the "Subgraph::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1" message whenever I try to use Subgraph (or HighlightGraph).  What might I be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<< Combinatorica`
```

> General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.

```
BB = Table[0, {i, 4}, {j, 4}];
BB[[1]][[2]] = 1;
BB[[2]][[1]] = 1;
BB
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

```
Gr = FromAdjacencyMatrix[BB];
Subgraph[Gr, {1, 2}]
```

> Subgraph::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in RowBox[{"Subgraph", "[", RowBox[{InterpretationBox[StyleBox[RowBox[{"[SkeletonIndicator]", "Graph:<", 0, ",", 4, ",", "Undirected", ">[SkeletonIndicator]"}], ShowAutoStyles -> False, AutoSpacing -> False], Graph[{}, {{{0, 1.}}, {{-1., 0}}, {{0, -1.}}, {{1., 0}}}], Editable -> False], ",", ({1, 2})}], "]"}]. >>

Answer (score 5):

`FromAdjacencyMatrix` construct combinatorica graph.  `Subgraph` and `HighglightGraph` accept system graph object.

Instead of loading Combinatorica package, you can just create graph from matrix by using `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
gr = AdjacencyGraph[BB]
```

Then `Subgraph` should work fine with it:

```
Subgraph[gr, {1, 2}]
```